# Linking text views to scroll together

Tags: ios, uitextview, swift2, xcode7

I have two side by side text views. How can I link them so that if one is scrolled down other automatically scrolls the same as first one in swift 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set your viewController conforms to `UITextViewDelegate`,then set textView delegate to self,then in `scrollViewDidScroll` sync both contentOffSet

For example
Gif

[image]

Code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textview2: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var textview1: UITextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textview1.delegate  = self
    textview2.delegate  = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == textview1{
        textview2.contentOffset = textview1.contentOffset
    }else{
        textview1.contentOffset = textview2.contentOffset
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I am not using scroll view. Just text views placed side by side. Just want the content to be scrolled equally whichever one is scrolled at runtime.

Comment: `UITextView` is subclass of `UIScrollView`,you can use any UIScrollView function @Bilal

Comment: It is not working for me. I don't know what did I do wrong.

Comment: Ok. I was making a minor mistake. Now it is working :) thanks. Is there anyway to set text view to display top content by default when page is loaded. Mine is scrolling to end automatically upon loading.

Comment: This is good, but what if you wanted to scroll one textview and have it also scroll another textview that was much longer so that it would still make the longer textview scroll to the end?